# 'pray to someone' vs 'pray someone'

Tags: differences, legalese

What are the similarities and differences? I had always believed in the first, that ['pray'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pray?q=pray) admits only an indirect object. Yet [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prayed+to+someone%2Cprayed+someone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprayed%20to%20someone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprayed%20someone%3B%2Cc0) refutes this.

For example, does the following admit of  'prayed to me' instead? Why or why not?

> During the reign of Alfred the Great (871–900), for example, a man
>   was accused of stealing a belt, and one of his accusers tried to claim his land. One writer of
>   the time recorded that the defendant ‘sought me and **prayed me** to be his intercessor. Then
>   I spoke on his behalf and interceded for him with King Alfred’.

Source: P47, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the citation you provide does not admit "prayed to me" as an equivalent. A mostly archaic usage of "pray" is as a synonym for "ask", especially when the one asking is of lower station than the one being asked, and in that case took a direct, rather than an indirect object. This usage survives, in part, in the expression "Pray tell", as in the sentence a father might use with a child, "Why did you run into the street, pray tell?"

Comment: It might be helpful to say that 'pray' in 'Pray tell' is an abbreviated version of 'I pray thee tell' which became 'Prithee tell'.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you. Please feel free to rewrite as a separate answer st I can +1.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with brasshat that in this particular case, the transitive *pray* is archaic usage for ask or beg, and closer to the original French sense:

> C13: from Old French preier, from Latin precārī to implore, from prex
>   an entreaty ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pray))

Perhaps you are thinking of cases like John 14:16

> And I will pray the Father, and he shall give you another Comforter,
>   that he may abide with you for ever (*Authorised Version/King James*)

where it sounds as if Jesus is praying to the Father. I will maintain that *pray* there still means 'ask'.